# Regex and javascript: match everything between number followed by space and by capital letter

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to be used with javascript.
This regex should be able to match everything between number + space + capital letter.

Here is an example:

```
var string = testtesttesttesttest1 This shuld be matched2 This shuld also be matched3 fdsfsfsd
```

From this string, I would like to get

```
[0] = 1 This shuld be matched 
[1] = 2 This shuld also be matched
```

I have tried this regex:

```
(?<=\d)(.*)(?=[A-Z])
```

But I can't find the one I need. Here is the example http://regexr.com?31reo

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var s = "testtesttesttesttest1 This shuld be matched2 This shuld also be matched3 fdsfsfsd";
var result = s.match(/\d [A-Z][^\d]+/g);
// ["1 This shuld be matched", "2 This shuld also be matched"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string.match(/\d [A-Z]\D+(?=\d)/g);

["1 This shuld be matched", "2 This shuld also be matched"]
```

Comment: you can omit square braces (`[]`) for `\D`. And i think it's useful to add `+` after the digit specificator. So, will get `/\d+ [A-Z]\D+/`

Comment: Yeah thanks, you're right I started to write [^\d] and forgot to remove :)